# Is there any specific number of output arrows from one activity in an activity diagram?

Tags: android-activity, software-design, diagram, use-case, activity-diagram

I am designing the activity model for a website, and I have a question about whether I have an activity that represents displaying a page on the website. This page contains several buttons, and each button represents an activity. How can I represent it? Can I, from the 'display page' activity, generate multiple arrows, each leading to a different activity? Is this correct or not?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show with your diagram? For example, what does "Delete Job" really mean? What relation does "Display an Image" have to the "Delete Job", "Update Job", "View Job", and "View Candidates" represent?

Comment: I apologize. There was a mistake in naming the activity.  browse the posted jobs Instead of displaying an image , what I want to represent is that the user can browse the jobs that he posted and then he will have several options such as deleting, modifying, or displaying this job, or showing the candidates for this job. @entpnerd

Comment: I'm assuming that the act of "Browse posted jobs" just takes you to a page where you browse a list of jobs associated with your own organization, and that this assumes that you are a recruiter, admin, etc. Are you able to view candidates, update a job, or delete job without drilling down on the individual job first?

Comment: it will like the following image  https://ibb.co/NL8Tz0d ,  when the user click on the "view" or "update" or "view candidates" each of this will forward the user to new page that related to job that the user selected . delete will delete job from the database and also from the list.  @entpnerd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you actually have at least four different use cases, e.g. "Recruiter Views Candidates", "Recruiter View Job", "Recruiter Updates Job", and "Recruiter Deletes Job", I think that activity diagrams do show these four cases adequately, based on what little I know about what you're trying to do. If an activity diagram is what you want, I would be inclined to use something like PlantUML and show your diagram as follows:

```
@startuml
start
:Browse Posted Jobs Page;
switch (Recruiter Decision?)
case ( View Candidates )
  :Show Candidate Page;
case ( View Job )
  :Show Job Page;
case ( Update Job )
  :Show Update Jobs Page;
case ( Delete Job )
  :Show Job Deletion Page;
endswitch
stop
@enduml
```

That code produces this image.
[image: UML description choices]

For reference, [this online PlantUML IDE snippet](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/PP2n3i8m34JtV8N7zXVAG0MTc2eGx26ngALILx6h_Zw6TaZ4bhkyItnkHNtIvJswty4rfyIh8FGiYX4k_1Je_GiFJbRIC41rnP0MKapGOI0Xdewr2zuo5Jm8LpZxALBqYWAr0sXk0sVc_beUi4yoqbJ9tETlhgGoKqgwmn7_Q5FRXKsxupZ5hP4LvzcrfcqB7m00).

For example of the generated output, see this output.